# How to detect lowercase letters

Tags: glfw

How one can detect lowercase letters with **glfw**? I can detect uppercase letters. For example,

```
if ( key == 'A' && action == GLFW_PRESS )
        std::cout << (char)key <<std::endl;
```

However, in the following code, nothing is printed out.

```
if ( key == 'a' && action == GLFW_PRESS )
        std::cout << (char)key <<std::endl;
```

and this is the declaration of the function

```
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if SHIFT key is pressed:

```
if ( key == GLFW_KEY_A && action == GLFW_PRESS ) {
    if (mode == GLFW_MOD_SHIFT) {
      //uppercase
    }
    else {
      //lowercase
    }
}
```

http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__mods.html

Comment: Just a reminder, if Capsloc is on then upper would be lower and lower would be upper, other than that this code will work

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue, eventually I found that for characters one better do this:

```
// Set the call back to the Char value pressed
glfwSetCharCallback(window, character_callback);
```

and your call back should look like this:

```
void character_callback(GLFWwindow* window, unsigned int codepoint) {
    if (codepoint == 'g') {
        // No need to check all combinations of RIGHT_SHIFT, LEFT_SHIFT, CAPS_LOCK
        std::cout << "lower case g pressed" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You can find more on this in the GLFW Input Guide: https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/input_guide.html

Hope this helps anyone who comes across this question, have a nice weekend.
Thanks,